# How to convert image path Into Base 64 Data URLs?

Tags: flutter

This is my code

```dart
var byte = File(item.path).readAsBytesSync();
        String img64 = base64Encode(byte);
```

And I have a result like:

```
(\/9j\/4TY3RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAALADIBAgAUAAAAkgAAABABAgAaAAAApgAAAAABBAABAAAAwAMAABMCAwABAAAAAQAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAAAEBBAABAAAAwAMAABsBBQABAAAAwAAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAAGmHBAABAAAA1wAAABoBBQABAAAAyAAAAA8BAgAHAAAA0AAAALUBAAAyMDIzOjExOjIxIDEzOjMyOjQ5AEFuZHJvaWQgU0RLIGJ1aWx0IGZvciB4ODYASAAAAAEAAABIAAAAAQAAAEdvb2dsZQAOAAGgAwABAAAA\)
```

But I want to have a result like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA3gAAALyCAYAAACIMnZEAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFUeJzsvXd8XMW9sP/MOWertGqWrGbLBSPbuIALtummGXAw5QIhJr/7JpDCJYSEAJeUl18wgRtyEyAJgSSQkJBGCwkdnFBMCS64gXvvsrosabX9nDPvH2d3t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to concatenate `data:image/png;base64,` with base64 String
like this:

```dart
var byte = File(item.path).readAsBytesSync();
String img64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64Encode(byte); // change png with the image extension you have
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dartk SDK includes a [`UriData` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/UriData-class.html) that can do it for you.

```dart
var bytes = File(item.path).readAsBytesSync();
var uriData = UriData.fromBytes(bytes, mimeType: 'image/png');
```

From there, you can use [`uriData.toString()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/UriData/toString.html) to get a `String` representation or [`uriData.uri`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/UriData/uri.html) to get a `Uri` object.